# How to debug isotp connection?

Tags: python, vector, can-bus

**my goal**: to connect to a device using udsoncan, isotp, can.
and I did not successfully connect,  and get data, I want to debug it.
how to do this?
I saw in the GitHub example that loggers all the process, with **full log** and I want also a log like this, I have loggers only to the Timestamp.

in GitHub:

```
INFO Connection:connections.py:449 Connection opened
DEBUG Connection:connections.py:51 Sending 2 bytes : [b'1001']
DEBUG isotp:protocol.py:478 Sending : <701> (8) b'0210010000000000'
DEBUG isotp:protocol.py:471 Receiving : 1627892866.389645 <701> (8) b'0210010000000000'
DEBUG isotp:protocol.py:471 Receiving : 1627892866.391792 <781> (8) b'065001003201f400'
DEBUG Connection:connections.py:78 Received 6 bytes : [b'5001003201f4']
DEBUG Connection:connections.py:51 Sending 2 bytes : [b'1003']
DEBUG isotp:protocol.py:478 Sending : <701> (8) b'0210030000000000'
DEBUG isotp:protocol.py:471 Receiving : 1627892866.523789 <701> (8) b'0210030000000000'
DEBUG isotp:protocol.py:471 Receiving : 1627892866.526788 <781> (8) b'065003003201f400'
DEBUG Connection:connections.py:78 Received 6 bytes : [b'5003003201f4']
DEBUG Connection:connections.py:51 Sending 2 bytes : [b'2701']
DEBUG isotp:protocol.py:478 Sending : <701> (8) b'0227010000000000'
DEBUG isotp:protocol.py:471 Receiving : 1627892866.649799 <701> (8) b'0227010000000000'
DEBUG isotp:protocol.py:471 Receiving : 1627892866.651773 <781> (8) b'066701cca8f3b600'
DEBUG Connection:connections.py:78 Received 6 bytes : [b'6701cca8f3b6']
DEBUG Connection:connections.py:51 Sending 6 bytes : [b'270200000000']
DEBUG isotp:protocol.py:478 Sending : <701> (8) b'0627020000000000'
DEBUG isotp:protocol.py:471 Receiving : 1627892866.796657 <701> (8) b'0627020000000000'
DEBUG isotp:protocol.py:471 Receiving : 1627892866.801785 <781> (8) b'037f273500000000'
```

in my:

```
 Timestamp: 1707120804.797365    ID: 1c440019    X Rx E              DL:  8    03 22 02 00 00 00 00 00     Channel: 1
Timestamp: 1707120804.798618    ID: 1c440019    X Rx E              DL:  8    03 22 02 00 00 00 00 00     Channel: 1
Timestamp: 1707120804.799871    ID: 1c440019    X Rx E              DL:  8    03 22 02 00 00 00 00 00     Channel: 1
Timestamp: 1707120804.801133    ID: 1c440019    X Rx E              DL:  8    03 22 02 00 00 00 00 00     Channel: 1
Timestamp: 1707120804.802386    ID: 1c440019    X Rx E              DL:  8    03 22 02 00 00 00 00 00     Channel: 1
Timestamp: 1707120804.803640    ID: 1c440019    X Rx E              DL:  8    03 22 02 00 00 00 00 00     Channel: 1
Timestamp: 1707120804.804901    ID: 1c440019    X Rx E              DL:  8    03 22 02 00 00 00 00 00     Channel: 1
Timestamp: 1707120804.806155    ID: 1c440019    X Rx E              DL:  8    03 22 02 00 00 00 00 00     Channel: 1
```

my code is like this:

```
bus = Bus(interface='vector', app_name='CANalyzer', channel=1, bitrate=125000)
notifier = can.Notifier(bus, [can.Printer()])  # Add a debug listener that print all messages

tp_addr = isotp.Address(isotp.AddressingMode.Normal_29bits, txid=0x1C440019,
                        rxid=0x1C460019)  # Network layer addressing scheme

stack = isotp.CanStack(bus=bus, address=tp_addr, params=isotp_params)  # Network/Transport layer (IsoTP protocol)
# Set up the ISO-TP connection using the appropriate CAN bus interface and parameters
tp_connection = PythonIsoTpConnection(stack)

# Set up the client with the ISO-TP connection
client = Client(tp_connection, config=config, request_timeout=2)

# Initialize the communication
client.open()
```